# Can We Create Temporary route in php or in codeigniter Which expires after certain period of time?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to create such a target route which expires after certain time.

If this is not possible, how can I create a target link which expires in a certain period of time in PHP.

If possible, can you give me some hints using CodeIgniter?

Otherwise, can you give me hints using pure PHP?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#callbacks

Comment: Create a route and check the validity in the callback/controller.